# recpatcha returns 200, still get error with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

All of my other searches yield responses about cross-domain requests.  It appears that I'm not having a problem with that.  I'm getting a response from the recaptcha server, but it's not being interpreted correctly.

```
<script>
function verifyCaptcha() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST" ,
        url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
        data: { secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" , response: "<% $recaptcha_response %>" },
        dataType: 'jsonp' ,
        success: function( result ) {
            alert( result.success ) ;
            },
        error: function( xhr ) {
            alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' Response Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
}
onload=verifyCaptcha ;
</script>
```

This function lives in a page that's the target of a submitted form.  When I check fireBug for the results, I get this in my alert message:

```
Request Status: 200 Status Text: success Response Text: undefined
```

And the response captured by FireBug is

```
{
   "success": true
}
```

It seems that it gets mad without the parens wrapped around the returned JSON which I thought were supposed to come free with `dataType: 'jsonp'`

How do I resolve the success of this?

***UPDATE***

Adding additional return parameters to the error funcion: `( xhr , message , errorThrown )` produced the following:

```
Request Status: 200
Status Text: success
Response Text: undefined
Message: parsererror
ErrorThrown: Error: jQuery1120043068059910713263_1455115913634 was not called
```

I'm guessing that the `jQuery1120043068059910713263_1455115913634 was not called` message is the callback function randomly named by jQuery.  Does this mean that I need to add something to my logic, or that the reCaptcha server does not indeed support jsonp ?

Setting the `dataType` to `"json"` gives me a request status of 0.

***UPDATE 2***

I added this to my function:

```
jsonp: false,
jsonpCallback: 'onJSONPLoad',
```

and my `errorThrown` text changed to:
`Error: onJSONPLoad was not called` which leads me to conclude that reCaptcha does not support `jsonp`.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Answer is:

The POST method is not available for jsonp, only GET

update:

As well as in the comment stated setting the dataType to`"json"` and it will automatically converted to jsonp, maybe try that

also you can add a third argument to the error function

```
error: function( xhr, message, errorThrown ) {
```

and errorThrown maybe is more explicit

Comment: While it is true that jsonp only works with GET, jquery will automatically ignore the method setting of POST and setup the call properly using a script tag. The op is wondering why the call is appearing to return properly but the json returned is causing the errror method to run.